# Monotouch Library Project does not include Images in "Content"

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a library project added to my solution. In this project is a png image set to "Content" in build action.

It does not appear in the app bundle though when compiled. Images in the main project do though.

How can I get images in projects that are not the main executable project appear in the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been working on support for content files and xibs in MonoTouch library projects, but I don't have an ETA for releasing this feature.

Until then, you will have to link the files directly into your executable project.

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2010-December/002504.html